# is there a function in Big Query that would allow me to subtract the latitude and longitude from starting and ending points?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple table with 4 columns.  The columns are starting_latitude, starting longitude, ending latitude, and ending longitude.  Is there a way to take the difference between the starting and ending lat/long coordinates and create a 5th column named difference?  The datatypes are FLOAT.

Comment: Why is using basic subtraction not sufficient for your requirement? `starting_latitude - ending_latitude`, etc.? Can you give some example inputs, what they *should* output, what code you've written so far, and why it doesn't meet those requirements? [ask]

Comment: @esqew, i think they are asking about the geographical distance between two points, not quite as simple as subtracting latitudes and longitudes.  while the question could be improved with sample data, i think there is enough to provide an answer

Comment: So I did not realize that you could calculate miles from the difference in a starting latitude and an ending latitude * 69.  That is the calculation I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your latitude and longitude to make geographic points, then use the `st_distance()` function to calculate the distance.

```
with data as (
    select 48.8566 as paris_lat, 2.3522 as paris_long, 40.7128 as nyc_lat, -74.0060 as nyc_long
),
points as (
    select st_geogpoint(paris_long,paris_lat) as paris, st_geogpoint(nyc_long,nyc_lat) as nyc from data
)
select
    paris,
    nyc,
    st_distance(paris,nyc)/1000 as distance_in_kms
from points
```

I used 2 popular cities as an example, but you could use your `starting_` and `ending_` lat/long columns.